# onclick hypertext link display select option

Tags: javascript

I want the script to load select option when onClick hypertext link
I am using the onclick handler to load a select option after clicking hypertext link, but nothing happens.
You can see a sample of my code below:

```js
function toggleTables(which) {

  if (which == "greenhouse") {
    document.getElementById('greenhouseselect').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('nethouseselect').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('sprinklerselect').style.display = "none";

  }
  if (which == "nethouse") {
    document.getElementById('greenhouseselect').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('nethouseselect').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('sprinklerselect').style.display = "none";

  }
  if (which == "sprinkler") {
    document.getElementById('greenhouseselect').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('nethouseselect').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('sprinklerselect').style.display = "block";

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <input type="checkbox" name="" value="greenhouse"><a href="#">Green House</a>
  <input type="checkbox" name="" value="nethouse"><a href="#">Net House</a>
  <input type="checkbox" name="" value="sprinkler"><a href="#">Sprinkler</a>
</div><br>

<div class="row">
  <div>
    <select id="greenhouseselect">
      <option value="310000">8 x 30 @ 310,000Ksh - Locally Fabricated</option>
    </select>
  </div><br>
  <div>
    <select id="nethouseselect">
      <option value="170000"> 8 x 15 @ 170,000Ksh - Locally Fabricated</option>
    </select>
  </div><br>
  <div>
    <select id="sprinklerselect">
      <option value="50000">Movable Systems 1 Acre @ 50,000 </option>
    </select>
  </div><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Well you never call or execute the function `toggleTables`

Comment: add onclick to call your function

Answer (score 0):

```js
function toggleTables(el) {
    if (el.tagName == 'A') {
        el = el.previousElementSibling;
        el.checked = el.checked ? 0 : 1; // strange bug != el.checked did not worked here
    }
    var others = el.parentElement.children, el2;
    for (var clearEm = 0; clearEm < others.length; clearEm++) {
        var eli = others[clearEm];
        if (eli.tagName == "INPUT" && eli != el) eli.checked = false;
    }
    var selection = "greenhouse|nethouse|sprinkler".split('|');
    for (var n in selection) {
        document.getElementById(selection[n]+"select").style.display = 
          (el.value == selection[n] && el.checked) ? "block" : "none";
    }
}
```

```css
select {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" onclick="toggleTables(event.srcElement)">
        <input  type="checkbox" name="" value="greenhouse"><a href="#">Green House</a>
        <input  type="checkbox" name="" value="nethouse"><a href="#">Net House</a>
        <input  type="checkbox" name="" value="sprinkler"><a href="#">Sprinkler</a>
    </div><br>

<div class="row">
            <select id="greenhouseselect">
                <option value="310000">8 x 30 @ 310,000Ksh - Locally Fabricated</option>
            </select>
            <select id="nethouseselect">
                <option value="170000" > 8 x 15 @ 170,000Ksh - Locally Fabricated</option>
            </select>
            <select id="sprinklerselect">
                <option value="50000">Movable Systems 1 Acre @ 50,000 </option>
            </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: How about when  before run code snipppet dont display any checkbox and only when click then display select options

Comment: It is better to use type=radio and set them same name in case you do not have checkboxes due to design preferences. (no need to clear others then)

Comment: i have change to radio but still  display all option before click.

Comment: Already here in snippet - simple default style: select {  display:none; } And also anchor click works now (you can see changes using edited link) - https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57989130/revisions.

Comment: Thanks alot, still one thing if you don't mind. You notice onclicking checkbox from greenhouse to sprinkler its <br> or spacing it down

Comment: No need for both DIV / BR, after removing there are no troubles with ;-)